# How can I add wince sdk 6 to embedded visual c++ 4?

Tags: c++, configuration, windows-mobile, embedded, windows-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why simple console app runs but dialog based does not run in WIN CE 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959134/why-simple-console-app-runs-but-dialog-based-does-not-run-in-win-ce-6-0)

I installed **Windows CE 5.0 Standard Software Development Kit (SDK).msi** and now I have STANDARDSDK_500 in eMbedded Visual c++ 4.

Now I have installed **Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Evaluation Edition.exe**. How can I add it to eMbedded Visual c++ 4. as STANDARDSDK_600?

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: We need some dll files. I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965480/779408).

Comment: @yms I would recommend you read the OP's comment and follow the link.  He had posted that as an answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here, but most importantly, eVC will only show SDKs .  I'm not sure exactly what "**Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Evaluation Edition.exe**" is in your context, but I doubt it's an SDK, since the SDK roller doesn't generate EXEs.

You must build and install an actual SDK.  This *must* be created with Platform Builder.  Thankfully, Microsoft abandoned the "Stndard SDK" after CE 5.0, so there is no out-of-the-box general SDK you can install.  You need to generate one (which is pretty simple since it seems you've installed Platform Builder) or get one from an OEM.

Also, since you have PB 6.0 installed, which installs Studio 2005, why are you using eVC?  You can do application development with Visual Studio.

Comment: Why "Thankfully"? The Standard SDK was usefull for .netcf development.

Comment: I think the "Standard SDK" caused way more confusion and support headache than probably any other single thing Microsoft included in Platform Builder (which is why they dropped it).